# Kivy Garden in PyInstaller - stuck trying to trace import

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I have a Kivy-based Python project that I'm trying to build. It uses the NavigationDrawer component from Kivy Garden, through an import:

> from kivy.garden.navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer

I have a PyInstaller spec file for it which builds a distributable version. This version works well on my machine, but unfortunately not on other machines. Running the interpreter in the 'dist' version with the -v switch, it appears that when I run the distributable on my machine, the navigationdrawer component is not actually coming from inside my build folder. All the other imports show something like:

> import kivy.graphics.gl_instructions # dynamically loaded from C:\Users\me\myapp\dist\RACECA~1\kivy.graphics.gl_instructions.pyd

But the navigationdrawer import says:

> import kivy.garden.navigationdrawer
>
> """directory C:\Users\me\.kivy\garden\garden.navigationdrawer
>   C:\Users\me\.kivy\garden\garden.navigationdrawer\__init__.pyc matches C:\Users\me\.kivy\garden\garden.navigationdrawer\__init__.py
>   import kivy.garden.navigationdrawer # precompiled from C:\Users\me\.kivy\garden\garden.navigationdrawer\__init__.pyc"""

But noo! I don't want you to import them from c:\users. I want them to get nicely copied into my dist folder like all the other imports. I've tried adding c:\users\me to PyInstaller's pathex, the system PATH and PYTHONPATH without any joy. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The comedy font wasn't supposed to appear here... I just couldn't get SO's blockquote formatter to stop doing it. :)

Comment: I had configured spec file, my kivy py file working great, but when generate executable, it don't take any extra package or even .kv file too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Pyinstaller to recognize the path to Kivy Garden Matplotlib modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228334/getting-pyinstaller-to-recognize-the-path-to-kivy-garden-matplotlib-modules)

Answer (score 2):

You could just copy the navigationdrawer code from `C:\Users\me\.kivy\garden\garden.navigationdrawer` to your app directory, call the folder 'navigationdrawer' and replace the import with `from navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer`.

It's not quite the 'right' way to do it (there's probably some way to make pyinstaller copy it in), but it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing your garden packages into your app. i.e.

```
garden install --app navigationdrawer
```

This will create a libs/garden folder inside the current directory and place the garden packages in there, which should make it easier to include.

Comment: This actually doesn't work - it seems to still load from the wrong place. I'm guessing PyInstaller didn't pick it up as a dependency and didn't copy the lib over. I think the key to this is a PyInstaller directive of some sort, I just don't know what it might be.

Comment: After app install, try adding navigationdrawer as a [hidden import](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/develop/project/doc/Manual.html#listing-hidden-imports) in your pyinstaller spec.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with garden modules.  When I install like the following:

start cmd /C "garden install --kivy roulettescroll"
start cmd /C "garden install --kivy roulette"
start cmd /C "garden install --kivy tickline"
start cmd /C "garden install --kivy datetimepicker"

I add PyInstaller ... --hidden-import=kivy.garden.tickline --hidden-import=kivy.garden.roulette --hidden-import=kivy.garden.roulettescroll --hidden-import=kivy.garden.datetimepicker ...

I'm able to install and have no problems with Python picking up the modules.  Unfortunately, the datetimepicker shows up as white rectangles.  I have no idea what I might be missing.. But atleast I got past the import issue.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your python site packages there is a folder named garden, look in `__init__.py`. There is a explanation how to install navigationdrawer.

Comment: Please share more details here. Looking to get detailed steps on your sami technical guideance to full documents